# How get integer value from a enum in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a enum in my Model that corresponds to column in the database.

The `enum` looks like:

```
  enum sale_info: { plan_1: 1, plan_2: 2, plan_3: 3, plan_4: 4, plan_5: 5 }
```

How can I get the integer value?

I've tried

```
Model.sale_info.to_i
```

But this only returns 0.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `Model.sale_info.value.to_i`? e.g. `Model.sale_info.plan_1.to_i`

Comment: Nops... Because I don't know which plan its store at database. So I want to recover it and cast it as an `integer`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can get the integer values for an enum from the class the enum is on:

```
Model.sale_infos # Pluralized version of the enum attribute name
```

That returns a hash like:

```
{ "plan_1" => 1, "plan_2" => 2 ... }
```

You can then use the sale_info value from an instance of the `Model` class to access the integer value *for that instance*:

```
my_model = Model.find(123)
Model.sale_infos[my_model.sale_info] # Returns the integer value
```

Comment: I like this approach. When using `before_type_cast`, it’ll return a string if you’re on an unsaved record you’ve initialised like `Post.new status: :unapproved`, but an integer if it’s persisted.

Answer (score 164):

You can get the integer like so:

```
my_model = Model.find(123)
my_model[:sale_info] # Returns the integer value
```

**Update for rails 5**

For rails 5 the above method now returns the string value :(

The best method I can see for now is:

```
my_model.sale_info_before_type_cast
```

Shadwell's answer also continues to work for rails 5.

Comment: It is because 'enum' will create a method sale_info for your model, use [:sale_info] to get the property value instead of return from sale_info method.

Comment: Note that this method does not work if the model has not been saved.
The sale_info_before_type_cast value (and my_model[:sale_info]) is still a string if it my_model.sale_info has been assigned a string without a subsequent save.

Answer (score 66):

## Rails < 5

Another way would be to use `read_attribute()`:

```
model = Model.find(123)
model.read_attribute('sale_info')
```

## Rails >= 5

You can use `read_attribute_before_type_cast`

```
model.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:sale_info)
=> 1
```

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Updated the answer. You can use `read_attribute_before_type_cast`.

Comment: Before Rails 5, model.read_attribute('sale_info') equal to model[:sale_info]

Answer (score 6):

My short answer is `Model.sale_infos[:plan_2]` in case if you want to get value of `plan_2`

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a method in my Model to achieve the same in my Rails 5.1 app.

Catering for your case, add this into your Model and call it on the object when needed

```
def numeric_sale_info
  self.class.sale_infos[sale_info]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions here require you to have a record or model class in hand. Here is an approach where you can get the integer value from an enum without creating a record, by using Hash's `.key` method:

```
sale_info.key('plan_3')
=> 3
```

This is particularly useful if you're doing some ETL and mapping raw values to/from string values between systems that depend on the numeric integer value and/or the string value in different scenarios.

Note that this is probably not highly performant, as searching for a value in a hash (as opposed to a key) is not efficient. If you're processing millions of values/second or have an enum with (yuck) hundreds of values, you'll probably want to build a new hash that inverts enum's values and keys so you can do efficient lookups in the opposite direction.