# Plural of an enum called access

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an enum called access defined on an account model.

```
enum access: [:basic, :silver, :gold, :platinum]
```

which works fine, e.g. `account.gold!` sets the value to 'gold' and then `account.access` returns 'gold'. Accordingly, I should be able to list the hash of access values with the plural of `acesss`, but `account.accesses`, returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `accesses' for #<Account:0x00007f9e7827e408>
Did you mean?  access
               access?
           access=
```

If I do `'access'.pluralize` it returns `accesses`, so why isnt `account.accesses` working?

Comment: Are you sure that RoR pluralizes enums?  I know it will do that with database entities, but I don't see the point of doing that with an enum.

Comment: Yes it does,  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570511/1299362, and it can be useful because you can write methods that will continue to work after someone adds a different value to the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plural method needs to be called on the model class (not on the instance of the class):

```
2.5.3 :001 > Account.accesses
 => {"basic"=>0, "silver"=>1, "gold"=>2, "platinum"=>3}
```

See the example [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). See the actual code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L160). It defines the method on the class.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work if you try the plural form:

`Account.accesses`

The mappings are exposed through a class method with the pluralized attribute name.

Check the guide here: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html